# Factory Girl & Rspec controller test failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, tdd, factory-bot, rspec3

I am still fairly new to testing and still wrapping my head around Factory Girl, which I believe to be the culprit of this failure. As simple as the solution will probably be, I have searched other posts with the same failure message but the answers are not working for me.

I decided to learn BDD/TDD by building this simple blog app. Here is the failure message:

```
Failures:

  1) PostsController POST create creates a post
     Failure/Error: expect(response).to redirect_to(post_path(post))
       Expected response to be a <redirect>, but was <200>
```

The test:

```
RSpec.describe PostsController, :type => :controller do
    let(:post) { build_stubbed(:post) }

    describe "POST create" do
        it "creates a post" do
          expect(response).to redirect_to(post_path(post))
          expect(assigns(:post).title).to eq('Kicking back')
          expect(flash[:notice]).to eq("Your post has been saved!")
        end
    end
end
```

My Factory Girl file:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :post do
        title 'First title ever'
        body 'Forage paleo aesthetic food truck. Bespoke gastropub pork belly, tattooed readymade chambray keffiyeh Truffaut ennui trust fund you probably haven\'t heard of them tousled.'
    end
end
```

The controller:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

    def index
        @posts = Post.all.order('created_at DESC')
    end

    def new
        @post = Post.new
    end

    def create
        @post = Post.new(post_params)

        if @post.save
            flash[:notice] = "Your post has been saved!"
        else
            flash[:notice] = "There was an error saving your post."
        end
        redirect_to @post
    end

    def show
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

    private

    def post_params
        params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body)
    end
end
```

In case it's relevant, here's my Gemfile:

```
gem 'rails', '4.1.6'

...

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.1.0'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '~> 4.5.0'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers', require: false
  gem 'capybara'
end
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for your tests:

```
context 'with valid attributes' do
  it 'creates the post' do
    post :create, post: attributes_for(:post)
    expect(Post.count).to eq(1)
  end

  it 'redirects to the "show" action for the new post' do
    post :create, post: attributes_for(:post)
    expect(response).to redirect_to Post.first
  end
end
```

Personally I'd also separate some of those expects you did in to different tests. However, I don't know that testing that they're set that way is really necessary in a controller.

edit:
There is also an issue with your create action where in the event of it not successfully saving it will still try to redirect to the @post which will fail. Your test with invalid attributes should highlight this.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I definitely agree those expects look better separated. I tried them and the first spec passes but the second one is still failing: 

 `Failure/Error: post :create, event: attributes_for(:post)
     ActionController::ParameterMissing:
       param is missing or the value is empty: post`

Comment: Oops - updated my answer... Copy and paste victim :^)

Comment: No problem - I also added to my answer some more information about your create action

Comment: Good call! I'll change the if/else to accommodate that scenario.

Comment: You would have picked up on it with your tests anyway (assuming you tested if they had invalid attributes). Push on with testing; it is worth it!

Comment: I did test model validations so would a test to make sure the invalid attributes redirects back to the new_post_path be sufficient?